# How to click a button in webbrowser document without ID

Tags: c#, browser

I have a button, but I can't find the code to click it.

Maybe it's a Java button or something, but this is the information about it:

```
<div class="contractLink">
    <button class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf1.php?a=17&c=ad65e8';  return  false;" value="الارتقاء الى مستوى 2" type="button">
</div>
```

Please tell me how can I do this. I have tried:

```
HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name");
if (ele != null)
```

But there is no id.

Comment: You should clarify what your problem is and which language you are using. Java != Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't control the HTML, you will have to use `GetElementsByTagName` to get all buttons and find the one you need.

If there is only one button then it's simple matter of:

```
HtmlElementCollection buttons = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
if (buttons.Count > 0)
    buttons[0].RaiseEvent("onclick");
```

Otherwise you can iterate the buttons and find the proper one according to its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GetElementsByTagName()` as below:

```
 HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
 foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
 {
    String value = elem.GetAttribute("value");
    //identify the button by matching the name
    if (value != null && value.Length != 0 && value.equals("الارتقاء الى مستوى 2"))
    {
       //write your code here
    }
  }
```

**If there is only one button in the page, then simply use `elems[0]` as your button.**

```
 HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
 HtmlElement myButton = elems[0];
```

Comment: @mnaarr2010:I updated the case for tag `button`. To get the name, use `GetAttribute("name")`.

Comment: thanks put what do you mean with the name of button  i can't find it 
you mean the value or ?????

Comment: @mnaarr2010: I didn't notice, you don't have `name` either. In that case, I believe you could use the value to match. Option 1 is preferable as option2 doesn't work if there are more buttons (it becomes order dependent).